# SQL: Query 2 tables to get latest date for each record

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables that I want to query Customer and Service

Customer table

```
    cnum       lastName        Address       Phone        Comments      

     2         McKenzie        Main Street   1234567898   None
     3         Stevenson       South Street  1225448844   None
     4         Adams           North Street  1234545454   None
```

Service

```
     IncidentNum     cnum      serviceDate      status       category      LastUpdated

     x1               2        02-21-2013       Closed       Repair        02-21-2013
     c2               2        05-12-2013       Open         Installation  05-13-2013
     d2               3        05-01-2013       Closed       Repair        05-05-2013
     f2               4        05-12-2013       Open         Repair        05-12-2013
```

Basically what I want to do is display the records with latest update for each customer record, regardless if the status is Closed or Open.

Final:

```
    cnum    lastName     Address        Phone        Category       Last Service
     2      McKenzie     Main Street    1234567898   Installation   05-13-2013
     3      Stevenson    South Street   1225448844   Repair         05-05-2013
     4      Adams        North Street   1234545454   Repair         05-12-2013
```

Im using OLEDB, this is for my project in VB.
Any input would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you tried using MAX(LastUpdated) in your query?

Comment: Yes I have but all it does is return one record which is the latest updated record from the service table.

Comment: so @Mariell .. that is what you want .. right? .. latest record from service table???

Comment: @pratik garg - I want the latest record for each customer

Comment: @marc_s - I am using ACCESS Database

Comment: can you please post your query as well?

Comment: `select customer.custNum, customer.lastName,     customer.address, customer.phone, service.category, service.lastupdated from customer inner join service on customer.custNum = service.custNum WHERE lastUpdated = (select max(lastupdated) service, customer on customer.custNum = service.custNum) group by customer.custNum`

Comment: I don't know Access SQL, but in regular MS SQL, you could use a `PARTITION BY` to get the top 1 for each customer, ordered by the ServiceDate. Access might have something similar. In this case, though, something like T-SQL's `MAX()` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: In your nested SQL statement, try selection only last updated field. You have where condition and selecting multiple values!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple.. see you have to join these two tables on **cnum**and then top of that you can put condition for latest/maximum servicedate..

You can use following query for the same task -

```
select customer.cnum,
       customer.lastname,
       customer.address,
       customer.phone,
       service.category,
       service.servicedate 
  from customer,service
 where customer.cnum = service.cnum
   and service.servicedate = ( select max(serviceDate) from service service2
                                where service2.cnum = customer.cnum)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for..

**Edit**: Editing query to display the customer info which is not present in service table

```
select customer.cnum,
       customer.lastname,
       customer.address,
       customer.phone,
       service.category,
       service.servicedate 
  from customer left outer join service on (customer.cnum = service.cnum)
   where (service.servicedate = ( select max(serviceDate) from service service2
                                where service2.cnum = customer.cnum)
          or service.cnum is null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input pratik, I have tried this query but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mariell: It would be great if you elaborated on that. Was there an error or just the wrong results?

Comment: I went back to double check and I noticed that I was missing a parenthesis. The query works now but the result is not exactly right. Would it be possible to display customer records that are not in the service table (ex: newly created customer that does not have an incident yet) along with customers that are in the service table (only the last updated record will display)?

Comment: @Mariell yes this is possible .. see my updated post along with the query you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
select c.cnum, c.lastname, c.address,
c.phone, s.category, s.servicedate 
from customer c,service s
where c.cnum = s.cnum
group by c.cnum
having s.LastUpdated = max(s.LastUpdated)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct customer.cnum,customer.lastname,customer.address,customer.phone,
service.category,
MAX(lastupdated)as lastservice from service,customer where service.cnum=customer.cnum
and service.servicedate = ( select max(serviceDate) from service service2
                            where service2.cnum = customer.cnum)
group by customer.cnum,customer.lastname,customer.address,customer.phone,
service.category
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.
I tested it and it gives the exact output you mentioned in the question.